# Can I even connect client-side JavaScript to google-analytics API?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api, client-side

I have been researching the google analytics api (GA4) for the past day. And I want to be able to use GA4 api functions like [runReport](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport) on the client-side. There is a piece of analytics that I want each of my web-clients to see.

Here is the code that I pulled out from the gapi documentation.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for analyticsdata.properties.runReport
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/code-samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("FILLED_THIS_WITH_MY_API_KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1beta")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.analyticsdata.properties.runReport({
      "resource": {}
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "FILLED_THIS_WITH_MY_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

And it gives me this error:

```
gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy\
```

Comment: Your code will not display our personal Google analytics data to your users.  Its going to show their data when they login.

Comment: may be related to https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/64

Comment: @DaImTo So the only way I could extract the data from my GA4 is by querying the gapi from a server?

Comment: To extract your own data then you would need to use a service account, client side JavaScript does not support service account authentication.  You would need to use a server sided language.

Comment: *is by querying the gapi from a server?* correct, but your client code can request the data through your server - the term is "proxy"

Comment: @DaImTo & Bravo, Thank you for confirming that! It's actually confusing that they use client-side scripts inside GA4 Data Api docs. Maybe it's meant to be used for the Universal Analytics. Google team need to check on that.

Comment: The Google analytics data api is used to extract data from google analytics GA4 accounts.  The google analytics reporting api is used to extract data from Universal google analytics accounts.

Comment: @Bravo not sure what you are talking about.  Service account authencation has noting to do with proxy servers.    A server sided programming language is a programming language that runs on a server as oopsed to client side running in the Brower like JavaScript.   Switch to Node.js

Comment: You're right, it has nothing to do with proxy servers - I'll have things I didn't say for 200, Alex